# Grant permissions on open for first time for a bound script in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I created a Google Spreadsheet template with a script bounded to it that, for example, when runs creates a copy of a Google Docs file with various tags in the text and replaces them with data from the spreadsheet or opens a prompt form where I can introduce some data and it fills cells with that. When the script runs for first time it request for user's authoritzation, the user has to give authoritzation, then the script stops running and him has to run the code again.

I would like to grant permits for all template copies or, if it's not possible, request for all authoritzations when de spreadsheet is opened for first time (all users that can create a copy of the template and access to it are always the same).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand that is not possible as your script is container-bound to the sheet (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound) so each time you copy the container you have to renew the permission.

See also
[What is the best way to create Container-bound Scripts that can be cloned?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62159168/what-is-the-best-way-to-create-container-bound-scripts-that-can-be-cloned)

The only way around it is to create a stand alone add-on (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/standalone).