# Publish as a private add-on to avoid granting permission on copies of gsheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a similar question to both of the questions below. I have a script bound to a google sheets, and I use this sheet as template. However I'm looking for an option to not have to grant permission each time I copy the file.
From reading the answers in the questions below, I understand I have to publish a standalone script as an add-on.
However, reading this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28990006/is-it-possible-to-publish-an-add-on-for-internal-use-without-approval-process#:%7E:text=An%20Add-On%20can%20be,Apps%20Script%20file%20is%20in.&text=An%20add-on%20can%20also,an%20add-on%20as%20unlisted.), I see that I need to create a Cloud Platform Dashboard and all bunch of stuff which looks pretty messy to me, such as google reviewing process. Again, it is only for personal use...
Is there a way I can privately publish it as an add-on, without having to go through all the process?
Thank you

[What is the best way to create Container-bound Scripts that can be cloned?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62159168/what-is-the-best-way-to-create-container-bound-scripts-that-can-be-cloned?noredirect=1&lq=1)
[Grant permissions on open for first time for a bound script in Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65006855/grant-permissions-on-open-for-first-time-for-a-bound-script-in-google-sheets)

Comment: You can always use a standalone script, if you don't want spreadsheet hook triggers like onEdit or button or anything else. Write a standalone script which loops through your spreadsheets doing what's needed.

Comment: if you have your own domain you can publish a domain-wide addon without going through the verification process.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want spreadsheet hook triggers like onEdit or button or anything else, You can use a standalone  script.

A standalone script can be written, which [loops through your spreadsheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app) doing what's needed based on [a time trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers).

Comment: Ok, thank you. Is there a way, however, to get a time triggered standalone script to loop through the spreadsheet of only one google drive folder?

Comment: @LoïcChabut Yes That is possible

Answer (score 0):

*Adding to the already existing answer*

Publishing a private add-on does not require going through the Google Review process, especially since it is for personal use only.

Therefore, the situations below **do not require** verification:

1. If you want to deploy the add-on solely for **internal use** which means that the add on will be used only by people in your Google Workspace or Cloud Identity organization.
2. If you want to use the add-on **domain wide** which means that the add on will be used only by Google Workspace enterprise users within the domain.

For the whole list of exceptions from the verification process, you can check this [here](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914?hl=en#exceptions-ver-reqts).

#### Reference

- [OAuth API verification FAQs](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914?hl=en).